# Signal to odd and even

Tags: signal-processing

I have a signal that is described below

$$x(t) = \begin{cases} -1, & t<0 \\ 
2t-1, & 0\leq t<1 \\
2-t, & 1\leq t<2 \\
0, & t\geq 2
\end
{cases}$$

$$x(-t) = \begin{cases} -1, & t>0 \\ 
-2t+1, & -1\leq t<0 \\
t-2, & -2\leq t<-1 \\
0, & t\leq -2
\end
{cases}$$

and I want to find the odd and even signal that $$x_0(t)+x_e(t) = x(t)$$

and then I have to find $$x_e(t) = \frac 1 2  (x(t)+x(-t))$$
$$x_o(t) = \frac 1 2  (x(t)-x(-t))$$

How to do it? Also I don't know if what I did is correct. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you define $g$ from $x$, but we can find odd and even parts of $g$.  Your $g(t)$ should allow $t$ to range over $(-\infty,\infty )$ as $x(t)$ does, not $[0,3)$.  For example, you should add a line to $g(t)$ saying $g(t)=-2$ if $t \lt 0$.  Then you would have values of $g(t)$ and $g(-t)$ at all times and you could substitute them into your last two equations.

Added:  the calculation of $g(t)$ is not correct.  It should be $$g(t) = \begin{cases} -2 & t\le 0 \\ 2t-2, & 0\leq t<1 \\ 
1-t, & 1\leq t<2 \\
-1, & 2\leq t

\end
{cases}$$

Comment: I tried to simplify it, then do what I need and in the end add 1 again to get the result.

Comment: @place_gpon:  I don't see the simplification.  There seems to be some confusion whether you are shifting in signal level or time as $x$ has no breakpoint at $3$

Comment: Maybe it was a bad idea. I removed the g things. Still don't know how to add them.

Comment: @place_gpon:  Now you have steps at $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$.  For example $x_e(t)=\frac 12 (-1 +0)=\frac{-1}2$ for $t \le -2$.  You just need to work it out at each step.

Comment: I will try to do it and I' ll post the result.